# Infinispan: class changed and deserialization not working

Tags: java, spring, serialization, deserialization, infinispan

I have a Spring Boot application using Infinispan 6.0.1.Final. I have two classes A and B. B extends A. And I have a cache storing objects of type B. Now, I did an small change, I moved 2 class fields and its getter/setters from B to A, and I have updated the serial id in both classes. When I start my application back, and I pull objects of type B from the cache, the fields I have moved appear as null.

My question is: the cache contains objects of type B (the old version of B). I have changed class B, but from a semantic perspective, the class remains with the same fields and methods because the fields I have moved are now in the parent class. Is it possible to have deserialization working just like before changing the classes?

Answer (score 1):

You should only rely on Java Serialization when you know that you can delete all data from Infinispan when you make changes to the class definitions of your objects.

For portable object representations, use the Protobuf encoded objects:

- http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#storing_protobuf_encoded_entities

With protobuf you have better control on how you want your data to evolve when the schema is updated. Incidentally Infinispan supports it very well, as it's the base requirement to support Remote Queries and several other advanced features.